# Theme Editor Not Showing

Tags: themes, editor

I made a custom WordPress theme from scratch for a client, then zipped it up and sent it to them. They installed the theme fine, but for some reason the theme editor does not display. What I mean is there is no link to "Editor" under appearance anymore. Does anyone know why this would happen? We had all plugins disabled at one point and it still wasn't showing. I was able to get to the theme editor on my own test website.

Comment: Does you client have the permissions necessary to use the theme editor?

Comment: Check your `wp-config.php` file and look for `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`

Comment: Yes he's showing as the administrator.

Comment: @howdy-mcgee Thanks! I'll pass this info on and we'll see if that's the issue.

Comment: What are the ___file permissions___ on the theme files?